# Is there a way to execute a bash command script by clicking a link on a web page?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This might be a stupid question, but it would great to be able to do this. I have a custom made admin section on a website of mine. I have a cron job set to run this file once a day /opt/webalizerScript.sh however, I would like to easily be able to execute that command from my admin section any time I want a fresh update on traffic stats from webalizer. I don't really want to edit the cron, because I don't intend on executing the script manually very often and once per day is fine for automated purposes. Granted I know I can just execute the script in a shell, but that negates the whole purpose of what I am trying to do.

Comment: What language are your site using on the server-side?

Comment: English. Programmingwise I'd like to use php or perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Amadan's answer is a good overview, I thought I'd drop in a simple php script as a demonstration.  This script assumes that bash will be the default shell of your web server.

demo.php runs "ls -alFh" but you can substitute any command

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Output of my bash script</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Output of my bash script</h1>
<pre>
<?php system("ls -alFh", $rc); ?>
</pre>
    <br>
    <?php echo "Return Code: {$rc}\n"; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome... thank you! Is there a way to verbose it on the page so I can see it happening just like I can in shell? This is why I have: `<?php system("/opt/webalizerScript.sh", $rc); ?>` It works perfect, however, the script takes a few moments to process and it would be great to be able to watch it process.

Comment: It can only output what your script outputs.  Does your script take a --verbose or some such?  Add any extra arguments at the end of the command string just like you would type it at the prompt. Can you add things to the script to show it's progress (such as echo commands)?  system() will flush the output line by line.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: It does not. Just has a bunch of these lines, each line updates webalizer stats for each website on my server. Here is an example of the first line: `#!/bin/sh
webalizer -n clarksvillecomputers.com -o /var/www/clarksvillecomputers.com/public_html/webalizer /var/www/clarksvillecomputers.com/logs/access.log
`

Comment: Do you see all the lines at the end when it finishes?  If so, your php installation may have some sort of caching turned on--see about disabling it.

Comment: Your script may be writing to stderr instead of stdout.  Try appending " 2>&1" to the end of the command.  Or read the comments at the end of http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php.  They talk about ways of capturing both.

Comment: Sorry, where does the `2>&1` go? Like this: `<?php system("/opt/webalizerScript.sh 2>&1", $rc); ?>` ?

Answer (score 2):

Executing scripts as response to HTTP requests is the very definition of CGI.

Your script will receive some environment variables to reflect the details of the request, and some standard input. At the end, whatever it outputs will be sent to the client. You have to output `Content-Type: text-plain` (or some other content type) followed by a blank line at the beginning.

Look into configuring your web-server for serving CGI; in Apache, you'll most likely just need to put your script in a `cgi-bin` directory.

That should be enough to get you started. There are plenty of tutorials on CGI for more info.